# Node express gets 2 calls from single remote ajax call

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple ajax call and when I debug on server side (node) I alays get 2 calls... 
I thought it was becuase of favicon but I dont think it is because I

app.use(express.favicon('public/assets/favicon.ico'));

I even tried to just do a catch all for favicon so I am pretty sure its the not the issue:

```
app.post('/_html/favicon.ico', function (req, res) {
   console.log('2222');
   res.send('{"serverName": 1}');
```

});

here is the ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: some_url.html,
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: '{a: 1}',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (res) {
        alert(res.serverName);
        console.log(res.serverName);
    },
    error: function (res) {
        alert("Bad thing happend! " + res.statusText);
        console.log("Bad thing happend! " + res.statusText);
    }
});
```

and for some reason when I debug on node server side, I always get 2 calls from ajax

:(

why?

Thanks,

Sean.

Comment: How many HTTP requests are being generated

Comment: 2 requests onto the same exact URI path

Comment: I am thinking maybe its becuase I am using cross domain so it has to send another call for checking something first, I am not sure... just seems odd

Answer (score 1):

It's [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

Cause you yse non-standard content type browser first send `OPTIONS` request and then real `POST` request with your data.

BTW, `{a: 1}` is invalid JSON. It must be `{"a": 1}`.